# About the issue of ineffective zoom function scaling in d3 v7

Tags: vue.js, d3.js

I have a question about d3 zoom function. I've been trying for a long time, but I haven't succeeded. I added a print statement in the zoomed function, and when I scroll the mouse, the console can output "11111111", but the zoom effect is not implemented. Here is my code. I appreciate any help you can provide!

```
<template>
  <div class="container">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import * as d3 from 'd3'
import {getAllPerson, getPersonByName} from "../../../api/bookSys/books";
export default {
  data() {
    return {
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    getAllPerson().then(res => {
      if (res){
        console.log(res)
        this.ForceGraph({
          "nodes": res,
          "links": []
        },{
          nodeId: d => d.id,
          nodeGroup: d => d.group,
          nodeTitle: d => `${d.id}\n${d.group}`,
          linkStrokeWidth: l => Math.sqrt(l.value),
          width:800,
          height: 600,
        })

      }
    })
  },
  methods: {
    // Copyright 2021-2023 Observable, Inc.
    // Released under the ISC license.
    // https://observablehq.com/@d3/force-directed-graph
    ForceGraph({
      nodes, // an iterable of node objects (typically [{id}, …])
      links // an iterable of link objects (typically [{source, target}, …])
    }, {
      nodeId = d => d.id, // given d in nodes, returns a unique identifier (string)
      nodeGroup, // given d in nodes, returns an (ordinal) value for color
      nodeGroups, // an array of ordinal values representing the node groups
      nodeTitle, // given d in nodes, a title string
      nodeFill = "currentColor", // node stroke fill (if not using a group color encoding)
      nodeStroke = "#fff", // node stroke color
      nodeStrokeWidth = 1.5, // node stroke width, in pixels
      nodeStrokeOpacity = 1, // node stroke opacity
      nodeRadius = 25, // node radius, in pixels
      nodeStrength ,
      linkSource = ({source}) => source, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
      linkTarget = ({target}) => target, // given d in links, returns a node identifier string
      linkStroke = "#999", // link stroke color
      linkStrokeOpacity = 0.6, // link stroke opacity
      linkStrokeWidth = 1.5, // given d in links, returns a stroke width in pixels
      linkStrokeLinecap = "round", // link stroke linecap
      linkStrength = 0.1,
      colors = d3.schemeTableau10,
      // colors = this.d3.schemeTableau10, // an array of color strings, for the node groups
      width , // outer width, in pixels
      height, // outer height, in pixels
      invalidation // when this promise resolves, stop the simulation
    } = {}) {
  // Compute values.
  const N = d3.map(nodes, nodeId).map(intern);
  const LS = d3.map(links, linkSource).map(intern);
  const LT = d3.map(links, linkTarget).map(intern);
  if (nodeTitle === undefined) nodeTitle = (_, i) => N[i];
  const T = nodeTitle == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeTitle);
  const G = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.map(nodes, nodeGroup).map(intern);
  const W = typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStrokeWidth);
  const L = typeof linkStroke !== "function" ? null : d3.map(links, linkStroke);

  // Replace the input nodes and links with mutable objects for the simulation.
  nodes = d3.map(nodes, (_, i) => ({id: N[i]}));
  links = d3.map(links, (_, i) => ({source: LS[i], target: LT[i]}));

  // Compute default domains.
  if (G && nodeGroups === undefined) nodeGroups = d3.sort(G);

  // Construct the scales.
  const color = nodeGroup == null ? null : d3.scaleOrdinal(nodeGroups, colors);

  // Construct the forces.
  const forceNode = d3.forceManyBody();
  const forceLink = d3.forceLink(links).id(({index: i}) => N[i]);
  if (nodeStrength !== undefined) forceNode.strength(nodeStrength);
  if (linkStrength !== undefined) forceLink.strength(linkStrength);

  const simulation = d3.forceSimulation(nodes)
    .force("link", forceLink)
    .force("charge", forceNode)
    .force("center",  d3.forceCenter())
    .on("tick", ticked);

//

  const svgContainer = d3.select(".container");
  const svg = svgContainer.append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .attr("viewBox", [-width / 2, -height / 2, width, height])
    .attr("style", "max-width: 100%; height: auto; height: intrinsic;");

// 添加矩形边框
  const borderWidth = 2; // 边框宽度
  const borderColor = "black"; // 边框颜色
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x", -400) // 边框与左侧的距离
    .attr("y", -300) // 边框与顶部的距离
    .attr("width", width - borderWidth) // SVG 的实际可视区域宽度
    .attr("height", height - borderWidth) // SVG 的实际可视区域高度
    .style("fill", "none") // 填充颜色为透明
    .style("stroke", borderColor) // 设置边框颜色
    .style("stroke-width", borderWidth); // 设置边框宽度

// 将 SVG 居中显示在屏幕中
  const containerWidth = svgContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().width;
  const containerHeight = svgContainer.node().getBoundingClientRect().height;
  const translateX = (containerWidth - width) / 2;
  const translateY = (containerHeight - height) / 2;
  svg.attr("transform", `translate(${translateX}, ${translateY})`);

  const link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("stroke", typeof linkStroke !== "function" ? linkStroke : null)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", linkStrokeOpacity)
    .attr("stroke-width", typeof linkStrokeWidth !== "function" ? linkStrokeWidth : null)
    .attr("stroke-linecap", linkStrokeLinecap)
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(links)
    .join("line");

  const node = svg.append("g")
    .attr("fill", nodeFill)
    .attr("stroke", nodeStroke)
    .attr("stroke-opacity", nodeStrokeOpacity)
    .attr("stroke-width", nodeStrokeWidth)
    .selectAll("circle")
    .data(nodes)
    .join("circle")
    .attr("r", nodeRadius)
    .call(drag(simulation));

  const g = svg.append("g");

  const zoom = d3.zoom()
    .scaleExtent([0.1, 10]) // 设置缩放的范围
    .on("zoom", zoomed); // 指定缩放时调用的函数

  function zoomed(event) {
    const transform = event.transform;
    g.attr("transform", `scale(${transform.k}) translate(${transform.x},${transform.y})`);
    console.log(event.transform)
    console.log(1111111111)
  }
  svg.call(zoom);



  if (W) link.attr("stroke-width", ({index: i}) => W[i]);
  if (L) link.attr("stroke", ({index: i}) => L[i]);
  if (G) node.attr("fill", ({index: i}) => color(G[i]));
  if (T) node.append("title").text(({index: i}) => T[i]);
  if (invalidation != null) invalidation.then(() => simulation.stop());

  function intern(value) {
    return value !== null && typeof value === "object" ? value.valueOf() : value;
  }

  function ticked() {
    link
      .attr("x1", d => d.source.x)
      .attr("y1", d => d.source.y)
      .attr("x2", d => d.target.x)
      .attr("y2", d => d.target.y);

    node
      .attr("cx", d => d.x)
      .attr("cy", d => d.y);
  }

  //拖动函数
  function drag(simulation) {
    function dragstarted(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
      event.subject.fx = event.subject.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.subject.y;
    }

    function dragged(event) {
      event.subject.fx = event.x;
      event.subject.fy = event.y;
    }

    function dragended(event) {
      if (!event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
      event.subject.fx = null;
      event.subject.fy = null;
    }

    return d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended);
  }

  return Object.assign(svg.node(), {scales: {color}});
}


  },


};
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOCf5.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BGh7.png)
This is the debugging I did.

Comment: I don’t see anything in your `g` (the element which you apply the zoom transform to): you append it but don’t add anything to it, you should use this `g` as the parent for everything you want to be affected by the zoom, instead of svg.append, use g.append.